# Dante multiple proxies with separate authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication, socks, dante

I have been trying to set up Dante on Debian to create a Socks 5 proxy. So far I have only managed to get it to work with the root user, and would like to know how I can have multiple proxies each with there own username and password.

I have figured out how to get authentication working, using the below:

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: venet0:0 port = 1080
external: 162.244.77.137
method: username
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: Jonglee
client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
pass {  
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate
        log: error # connect disconnect iooperation
        method: username
}
```

But now I am wondering how I can make it so I can use multiple IP addresses, some on the same usernames and some on different ones.

Comment: You should probably include some information about what you've done to configure it so far, ie. post the relevant server settings from `danted.conf`

Comment: Added more information now.